# getting exception during deserialization

Tags: java

```
public List<Show> populateDataFromFile(String fileName)
 {
    List<Show> shows= null;
    try{
        ObjectInputStream in=new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
        shows= (List<Show>) in.readObject();
       in.close();

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


      return shows;

 }
```

I'm getting `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.bean.Show cannot be cast to java.util.List`

I've performed deserialization to initialise data of show class that is already serialized. I also make show class as serializable by implementing serializable i/f. I think readObject `method` can't convert into `ArrayList`.. Please tell me how do I convert it?

Comment: Could we see the serialisation as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've written in the file, must be an instance of the Show class, not a `List<Show>`.
Perhaps, instead of `outputStream.writeObject(list);` you did something like `for(Show show: list) outputStream.writeObject(show);`?
Try reading it back the same way:

```
List<Show> shows = new ArrayList<Show>();
try {
    while(true) {
        shows.add((Show) in.readObject());
} catch (EOFException e) {
   in.close();
   // end of file
}
```

Comment: valid theory there +1

Comment: thanx..your code is working but list is displaying fully qulified class name..but i want to initialise show class members from serialized file..actually i've got an assignment in which they privide me a serialised file,show class and ask me to implement a method that will initialise show class using deserialization..please help me..

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "list is displaying ..."

Comment: i mean when i write system.out.println(shows) it displays fully qulified class names..but then i have wriiten a for each loop to retrieve show class's variable's value and it's working..do you have any better solution than this?

Comment: You can implement `Show.toString()` method to return the information you want to print. Then `System.out.println(shows)` will print whatever that function returns for each element of the list.

Comment: thanks for ur help.. i also want to write a method as  public void bookShow(List<Show> showList,String showName,String show_time,int noOfSeats)throws SeatsNotAvailableException, UnknownShowException, InvalidSeatNumberException   this method should book ticket...the 1st argument should be list of show names..and now i have a shows list which has all values as show name,showtime etc but from that i only need showname ..how should i do it?plz help

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the Object you have serialized is a single object of `Show` and not a List of `Show`s as you are expecting, try to cast to `Show` only or check your serialization and make sure you are serializing a `List<Show>`.